# Interesting Integral with Parameters

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I would like to compute the following integral:
$$\int\frac{d^{2}\overrightarrow{q}}{2\pi}\int\frac{d^{2}\overrightarrow{k}}{2\pi}e^{i\overrightarrow{q}\cdot\overrightarrow{r}}\left(e^{i\overrightarrow{k}\cdot\overrightarrow{\rho_{1}}}-e^{i\overrightarrow{k}\cdot\overrightarrow{\rho_{2}}}\right)\frac{\overrightarrow{q}\cdot\overrightarrow{k}}{q^{2}k^{2}}\log^{2}\left(\frac{k^{2}}{q^{2}}\right)
 $$
Where $q$ is the length of a two component vector.

This integral appears in http://arxiv.org/pdf/0705.1885.pdf as eq (80) in the appendix.

As I'm stuck for quite a long time, I recently talked to one of the authors of this paper and the sent me an explanation how to reproduce it:

> 1. You represent $\log ^2$ as the second derivative w.r.t. $\nu$ at $\nu = 0$ according to  $\log ^2 (a) =\frac {\partial ^2} {\partial \nu ^2} \Big| _{\nu = 0} a^\nu$.
> 2. Exponentiate all the denominators according to (74).
> 3. Make full squares and Gauss-integrate out $q_1$ and $q_2$.
> 4. Substitute $a_1=u z, a_2 = u (1-z), a_3= u z \frac {1-z} {\frac 1 t-1}$ and Gauss-integrate w.r.t. $u$.
> 5. Decompose the result into simple fractions and drop the $\frac 1 t$ pole as it will not contribute after the differentiation.
> 6. Integrate the rest w.r.t. $t$.
> 7. Subtract the bare divergent at $\nu=0$ term $~ z^{-1+\nu}$ or something like that and add it.
> 8. Integrate the term you added w.r.t. $z$ and then take its second derivative in $\nu$ and set $\nu =0$.
> 9. Take the second derivative in $\nu$ of the rest and set $\nu =0$. It should not have divergences in $z$. You will have a dilogarithm
>      integral. Take it.
> 10. In the sum of 8 and 9 you should get (80).

Unfortunately, all the steps after step 5 are not clear to me. Can someone help me with that please? Your help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the variable of integration in the outermost integral?

Comment: BTW: this integrals seems to be heavily related to some multiple loop calculations in QED/QCD. Have you looked up the literature in this direction? Could well be that something like this is already calculated somewhere in this direction.

Comment: Indeed! it came from loop calculations in QCD. Yes, I looked in the literature. The paper http://arxiv.org/abs/0705.1885v1 calculated similar integrals in (89) and (90) in appendix B. Unfortunately, after spending alot of time on it, I didn't managed to reproduce these results.